# Grafana - table row count not always calculated

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am displaying a table of information in Grafana and have turned on the table footer to display the current count of items in the table. However, it's showing a blank value. After some experimentation, it appears that it will only perform an operation for the footer (e.g. count, total, etc.) if the column representing the query result is available and included.

In some cases this is fine, as I want to display that column anyway. But in other situations, the result is just a `1` and just clutters the view (as well as wasting a column). I have also had cases where there was no "result value", in which case there's nothing to show, and hence no way to show the row count.

Is there a way to show the table row count for these types of use cases?